# View showing black triangles when rotating the camera

Tags: xcode, camera, scenekit

I have an image with 6 sides set as background image for camera (as a skybox) and everything worked fine, until I updated Xcode to Xcode 8. Now the camera shows black patches in shape of triangles as if it were intersecting with the skybox when rotating.

I have almost everything set in Scene Editor so I have no relevant code to post.

I can't find anything about changing the size of the box created for skybox or anything like that. Can setting some camera properties solve that?

**EDIT: Added a screenshot.**

[image]

**ANOTHER EDIT:**

With using an actual device there are no similar problems.

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot to make the issue easier to understand ?

Comment: Of course, I added a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The camera in Xcode 8's Scene Kit has much more aggressive Z distance clipping. This is the distance before the camera stops rendering (or seeing) what's past a certain distance from it. Or too close to it.

This looks somewhat like that, but not quite. Normally sky boxes are immune to Z-clipping, a special case where it's not needed.

Distance clipping exists to prevent the need to draw (the many) things (and calculate them) that might be so far away that they're not visible, or not necessary to the game's function, and just calculation overhead.

Select your Camera in the Node tree or screen, and adjust the Z-clipping Far value (in the Inspector) to something double or triple what it currently is. This might solve this problem.

If it does, I'd suggest that Z-clipping impacting the rendering of a Skybox is a bug.

Comment: Changing both near and far Z-clipping value has no effect on the problem, but I did notice something I did not before. Apparently the problem is not with camera but the skybox itself, because the only thing that gets clipped of (has black triangles over it) is the skybox itself. Could there be something wrong with my image I used as a cube map?